# The procedure of delete node in the queue class

Tags: c++, c++11

This code is copied from the c++ primer plus. I think some
 steps in the dequeue function is unnecessary. But the book
 say it is important.I don't understand. I hope some one can show me more detail explanation.Here is the definition of the queue.

```
typedef unsigned long Item;
class Queue
    {
    private:
        struct Node{ Item item; struct Node * next; };
        enum{ Q_SIZE = 10 };
        Node * front;
        Node * rear;
        int items;             // the number of item in the queue
        const int qsize;
        Queue(const Queue & q) :qsize(0){};
        Queue & operator=(const Queue & q){ return *this; }
        Queue & operator=(const Queue & q){ return *this; }
    public:
        Queue(int qs = Q_SIZE);
        ~Queue();
        bool isempty()const;
        bool isfull()const;
        int queuecount()const;
        bool enqueue(const Item & item);
        bool dequeue(Item & item);
    };

bool Queue::dequeue(Item & item)
{
    if (isempty())
        return false;
    item = front->item;
    Node * temp;
    temp=front;              // is it necessary
    front = front->next;
    items--;
    delete temp;
    if (items == 0)
        rear = NULL;   //why it is not front=rear=Null ;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, that is an absolutely terrible book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes in this queue are stored as pointers. To actually create a node some code like `Node* tmp = new Node()` is probably somewhere in the enqueue-Function.

With `front = front->next;` the pointer to the first element gets moved to the next element in the queue. But what about the previous `front`-node? By moving the pointer we "forget" its adress, but we don't delete the object or free the memory. We have to use `delete` to do so, which is why the adress is temporarily stored to call the delete. Not deleting it would cause a memory leak here.

About your second question: The `front`pointer has already been moved to `front->next`. What could that be if there was only one element inside the queue? Probably `NULL`, which should be ensured by the `enqueue`-function. ("Note: If you are managing this code, it is a good idea to replace `NULL` with `nullptr`).
The only variable that didn't get updated yet is `rear`.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = front;
```

saves a pointer to the front element so it can be deleted after `front` has been modified.

If the queue is empty, `front = front->next;` has already set `front` to null, so there's no need to do it again.

Comment: Thank you for your help!